# I just can't beat the Reaper on Rannoch in ME3

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have read all the tips and I just can't do this particular mission.  I am really looking for some kind of save game editor to allow you to finish the mission or something of that nature.  I've tried the only save game editor (gibbed) I can find but the option of completing a mission is not available.

Is there any kind of cheat that will get me through this?  I would even accept a save game from someone else understanding that I would have to use their Shepard to finish the game.

Comment: Same question found here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54158/how-do-i-beat-the-reaper-on-rannoch.  **EDIT**: Oh yeah, I missed the first few words.  I'll keep this here anyway.

Comment: @Jamal It's still been asked already, so this is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: @fbueckert: Okay, just making sure.

Comment: It's not really a duplicate. The other question was asking for help beating the boss. This one is asking for help skipping it entirely. This question could be extrapolated to help with any boss somebody wants to skip without killing making it a different question.

Comment: It is not that hard. You need to go to the left / right direction and after it starts to shoot change direction. That way the laser beam will go into the other direction and you can stay in one place and target the red firing chamber. Another option that instead changing direction you roll twice or 3 times and do the same. You cannot aim with that laser tool while you are moving.